# From html input="date" to html select drop down format

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to convert html tag/format `<input type="date">` to html tag/format `<select><option></option></select>` ?

I just wanted to make an input type date to a select drop down format.

For example:

From

Date of Birth - input type date

To

Date of Birth - select drop down option

Actually, I don't want to separate the date of birth values into three. But instead, make a better solution wherein I can transform the input date into a select drop down one.

Anyone who can help me with this one? Thank you.

Comment: a select dropdown with 36 thousands rows, does not sound like fun

Comment: Depending upon the browser, the type=date should open a dialog that allows people to quickly enter a date. If you want to provide a suggested list of dates you can change your input to type='text' then use a datalist. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist

Answer (score 1):

You may use jQuery plugin to showcase a **datepicker** like the one below:

https://plugins.jquery.com/datetimepicker/

You can easily find many other jQuery plugins for the same.

If you wish to play around with its UI, you may use **jQuery UI** built-in themes or write some CSS on your own.

Answer (score -2):

Depending on the browser to open dialog. and also input type=date not support in every browser.